# Alert generation after apache server shut down

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat

I want to generate alert as email or sms as soon as the Apache tomcat server instance shuts down due to power failure or hard system reboot or some other reason. Please can any one help me how can i achieve this requirement or weather it is possible or not.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a script running on an external server which query a site on the Tomcat server and if the script fails to query the site on the Tomcat server for a certain number of requests, it sends a mail.

If you want something robust Nagios will suit well else a simple bash script will also do fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor the server using monitoring tools such as icinga2, nagios. Normally in icinga2 there is an email and sms notification which can be made possible by configuration. 
If you want something lighter you can install cacti and have it monitor the server through cacti there are plugins that can be added to notify users through sms and email if anything happens to the server.